# Ariflow - ExternalTaskMarker not clearing downstream

Tags: airflow

I want to be able to clear downstream tasks in Airflow even the ones that are in different DAG. I thought I can use `ExternalTaskMarker` but even after following official example - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/example_dags/example_external_task_marker_dag.html I am not able to get it work.

When I clear downstream parent task, nothing happens in the child dag, or, to be more precise - child task is `up_for_reschedule` all the time.

How to make this work?